# Javascript - Detecting the first character and alerting the user

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a question.  I'm wanting to run a basic function in Javascript which takes an input field from a form and checks the very first character to ensure it does not have a £ sign (GBP) infront of the value

I can't seem to find the right code anywhere to do this? - Anyone have any idea's... I'm a bit of a noob to all this programming to be honest so any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an input field and you want to get it's value and check the first character of the value, you can do so like this:

```
<input type="text" id="price">


var str = document.getElementById("price").value;
if (str.charAt(0) == "£") {
    // do whatever you need to do if there's a £ sign at the beginning
}
```

If the £ sign isn't supposed to be there, perhaps you could just safely remove it or ignore it rather than make the end user remove it like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("price");
if (el.value.charAt(0) == "£") {
    el.value = el.value.substr(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your HTML is something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="my_input" />
<button onClick="checkInput();">Check input</button>
```

Then you want to build your script like this:

```
function checkInput() {
    var inp = document.getElementById('my_input'); // get the input field
    inp = inp.value; // get the value
    inp = inp.charAt(0); // get the first character
    if( inp == "£") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

That can be condensed into:

```
function checkInput() {
    if( document.getElementById('my_input').value.charAt(0) == "£") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The trick to any code-writing is breaking a big problem into smaller ones. Step by step.

Answer (score 0):

[charAt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp) should do it

```
var str = "Foo";

var firstChar = str.charAt(0);
```